# How to return JSON from action in struts 2

Tags: json, struts2

I want to return a large JSON response from my struts action class.
I have made a Dynamic web project in eclipse without using maven of any other tool.

So what I need to do for this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps

**Step 1 pom.xml**

```
<!-- Struts 2 -->
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
  <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.8</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Struts 2 JSON Plugins -->
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
  <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using maven you can add jars manually and copy them in your WEB-INF/lib folder.

**Step2 Make Action**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;

public class JSONDataAction{

private String string1 = "A";
private String[] stringarray1 = {"A1","B1"};
private int number1 = 123456789;
private int[] numberarray1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
private List<String> lists = new ArrayList<String>();
private Map<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();

//no getter method, will not include in the JSON
private String string2 = "B";

public JSONDataAction(){
    lists.add("list1");
    lists.add("list2");
    lists.add("list3");
    lists.add("list4");
    lists.add("list5");

    maps.put("key1", "value1");
    maps.put("key2", "value2");
    maps.put("key3", "value3");
    maps.put("key4", "value4");
    maps.put("key5", "value5");
}

public String execute() {
           return Action.SUCCESS;
    }

public String getString1() {
    return string1;
}

public void setString1(String string1) {
    this.string1 = string1;
}

public String[] getStringarray1() {
    return stringarray1;
}

public void setStringarray1(String[] stringarray1) {
    this.stringarray1 = stringarray1;
}

public int getNumber1() {
    return number1;
}

public void setNumber1(int number1) {
    this.number1 = number1;
}

public int[] getNumberarray1() {
    return numberarray1;
}

public void setNumberarray1(int[] numberarray1) {
    this.numberarray1 = numberarray1;
}

public List<String> getLists() {
    return lists;
}

public void setLists(List<String> lists) {
    this.lists = lists;
}

public Map<String, String> getMaps() {
    return maps;
}

public void setMaps(Map<String, String> maps) {
    this.maps = maps;
}

}
```

**Step 3 Struts.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
 "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
 "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
  <action name="getJSONResult" 
       class="com.mkyong.common.action.JSONDataAction">
       <result type="json" />
  </action>
 </package>

 </struts>
```

Run the project and output will be http://localhost:8080/Struts2Example/getJSONResult.action

[image: output]

```
{
"lists":["list1","list2","list3","list4","list5"],
"maps":
 {
  "key4":"value4","key3":"value3","key5":"value5","key2":"value2","key1":"value1"
},
"number1":123456789,
"numberarray1":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
"string1":"A",
"stringarray1":["A1","B1"]
}
```

Just make sure in your struts.xml your workspace extends json workspace

```
 <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
```